Getting :- Error retrieving tokens: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token
So I have been trying to make an extension using MyAnimeList API to fetch user data and upon callback after authorization of the user.
def mal_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    code_verifier = request.session.get('code_verifier')

    if not code or not code_verifier:
        return redirect('/error/')

    # Prepare credentials and payload for token exchange
    credentials = f"{settings.MAL_CLIENT_ID}:{settings.MAL_CLIENT_SECRET}".encode('utf-8')
    encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials).decode('utf-8')
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': settings.MAL_CLIENT_ID,
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': settings.REDIRECT_URI,
        'code_verifier': code_verifier,
    }

    try:
        token_response = post(
            'https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token',
            headers={
                'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_credentials}',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data=token_data
        )
        token_response.raise_for_status()
        token_response_json = token_response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving tokens: {e}")
        return redirect('/error/')

    if 'error' in token_response_json:
        print(f"Token error: {token_response_json['error']}")
        return redirect('/error/')

    access_token = token_response_json.get('access_token')
    refresh_token = token_response_json.get('refresh_token')

    # Retrieve user info from MAL
    try:
        user_info_response = get(
            'https://api.myanimelist.net/v2/users/@me',
            headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
        )
        user_info_response.raise_for_status()
        user_info_json = user_info_response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving user info: {e}")
        return redirect('/error/')

    username = user_info_json.get('name')
    if not username:
        return redirect('/error/')

    # Create or get user and external user records
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
    expires_in = token_response_json.get('expires_in')
    expires_at = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=expires_in) if expires_in else None

    external_user, _ = ExternalUser.objects.update_or_create(
        user=user,
        defaults={
            'provider': 'MAL',
            'access_token': access_token,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token,
            'token_expires_at': expires_at,
        }
    )

    login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')

I rechecked all variable and constant values and all of them seem to be correct, I have recheck all of them multiple times
Edit: When I run this code I get redirected to '/error/' since that is what is configured if any error arises and I don't get redirected to my '/' as intended

What happens when you run this code?  The code has several error logging lines, but you didn't post the traceback of when this fails.  That would help people assit you with the issue, to undertand where this code is failing.
